# How to use html in elastalert?

Tags: kibana, elk, elastalert

I am working with ELK stack and have setup elastalert to monitor kibana-logs. I have created a simple elastalert rule and i am trying to use html inside my rules file but it's not rendering the html in the alert.

This is what my rules file look like :-

```
es_host: localhost
es_port: 9200
name: New Test Rule
type: frequency
index: logstash-*
num_events: 1
realert:
  minutes: 3
timeframe:
    hours: 4
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "no"
alert_text_type: alert_text_only
alert_text: "<h5>Test!!!</h5>"
alert:
- command
command: ["/home/ubuntu/elastalert/script.sh"]
```

If someone knows how to parse html in an alert. I sure can use some assistance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration, you simply need to specify the [`email_format` setting](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#email):

```
email_format: html
```

> `email_format`: If set to `html`, the email’s MIME type will be set to HTML, and HTML content should correctly render. If you use this, you need to put your own HTML into `alert_text` and use `alert_text_type: alert_text_only`.